# arquitectura MVVM con fiirebase firestore

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

hola estoy con un problema hace bastante nesecito llevar el valor de un textview hasta un datasource para completar la query a firebase.El valor  estoy pasando por constructor en el fracment por el viewmodel. pero llega null. alguien sabe como puedo llevar ese valor?
Aqui les dejo los bloques de codigo del camino de que hace desde el fracment hasta el datasource
esto es en fragment

```
      viewModel.favoristos(id).observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
                when (it) {
                    is Result.Loading -> {
                        binding.deltarelative.show()
    
                    }
                    is Result.Succes -> {
                        binding.detallesO.adapter = adapterDetalles(it.data)
                        binding.deltarelative.hide()
                    }
                    is Result.Failure -> {
                        binding.deltarelative.hide()
    
                        Toast.makeText(
                            requireContext(),
                            "ocurrio un error:${it.exception}",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        ).show()
    
                    }
    
                }
            })
        //la clase viewmoel
        class viewModelPost (private val repo: HomeInt) :ViewModel(){
        fun favoristos(id:String) = liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {
            emit(Result.Loading())
            try {
                emit(repo.Producto(id))
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                emit(Result.Failure(e))
            }
        }
           la insterface
            suspend fun Producto(id :String):Result<List<DataSource>>
        
        //esto el el datasource
     

suspend fun getOferts(id_:String): Result<List<DataSource>> {
        val listClientes = mutableListOf<DataSource>()
        val data_id = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("comercios/$id_/ofertas").get().await()
            for(document in data_it.documents){
                document.toObject(DataSource::class.java)?.let { index->
                listClientes.add(index)

            }
        }
        }
        
        return Result.Succes(listClientes)
    }


 //la implementacion
class HomeImp(private val data: DataSourceHome):HomeInt {

            override suspend fun Producto(id :String): Result<List<DataSource>> =data.getOferts(id)
```

Comment: Por favor lee el artículo [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Pon tu código, así sabremos que haces y como podemos ayudarte

Comment: listo ahiya lo edite

Comment: por favor cualquier cosa que puedan aportar

Comment: de dónde sale el valor del textView? del usuario o de un datasource? si viene de un datasource el ViewModel puede acceder a él y no hay que pasarlo por constructor.  Si viene del usuario, entonces una vez el usuario ponga su valor en el campo de texto, entonces es cuando puedes llamar al ViewModel para que pida datos al repositorio

Comment: el valor se lo estoy pasando por arg desde otro fragment  ahi yo lo cargo al textview. Como puedo hacer para que llegue al datasource??